# cyclic subspace for operators over infinite dimensional spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, differential-operators, invariant-subspace

Does there exist a cyclic subspace for an operator $\frac{d^2}{dt^2}$ over a space of $C^{\infty}$ functions? In general, are there differential operators with cyclic subspaces?